# Using Bootstrap Tour with Rails: "couldn't find file 'bootstrap-tour' with type 'text/css'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-tour

So I am trying to use Bootstrap tour with my web-app.

I already had Bootstrap installed...and I just followed the documentation here to get Bootstrap tour installed: https://github.com/tienle/bootstrap-tour-rails

So first I added `gem 'bootstrap-tour-rails'` to my gemfile. 
I bundle installed.
I added `//= require bootstrap-tour` to my application.js file. 
But then I seem to have an issue when I follow the final step in the bootstrap-tour rails instructions and add `*= require bootstrap-tour` to my application.scss file.

[Here is a screenshot of my error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi8AR.png)

My application.hmtl.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WalkThru Demo</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

my application.js file

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-tour
//= require popper
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

my application.scss file

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap-tour
 */
```

Comment: did you tried restarting the server?

Comment: I have a similar problem with it. How did you end up solving it?

Comment: I never got this resolved....I only needed a static page for what I wanted to do, so I scrapped the Ruby project and instead made a simple HTML page and integrated Bootstrap tour through that instead.